# How do I remove HTTP links with ActiveSupport's "starts_with" using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

When I try this:

```
item.css("a").each do |a|
  if !a.starts_with? 'http://'
     a.replace a.content
  end
end
```

I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'starts_with?' for #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1b48a60>
```

EDIT:

Sure there is a cleaner way, but this seems to be working.

```
item.css("a").each do |a|
  unless a["href"].blank?
    if !a["href"].starts_with? 'http://' 
      a.replace a.content
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to use the `starts_with` method on an object that doesn't implement it.

```
item.css("a").each do |a|
```

will return XML nodes in `a`. Those belong to Nokogiri. What you want to do is convert the node to text, but only the part you want to check, which, because it's a parameter of the node, can be accessed like this:

```
a['href']
```

So, you want to use something like this:

```
item.css("a").each do |a|
  if !(a.starts_with?['href']('http://'))
     a.replace(a.content)
  end
end
```

The downside to this is you have to walk through every `<a>` tag in the document, which can be slow on a big page with lots of links.

An alternate way to go about it is to use XPath's `starts-with` function:

```
require 'nokogiri'

item = Nokogiri::HTML('<a href="doesnt_start_with">foo</a><a href="http://bar">bar</a>')
puts item.to_html
```

which outputs:

```
>> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
>> <html><body>
>> <a href="doesnt_start_with">foo</a><a href="http://bar">bar</a>
>> </body></html>
```

Here's how to do it using XPath:

```
item.search('//a[not(starts-with(@href, "http://"))]').each do |a|
  a.replace(a.content)
end
puts item.to_html
```

Which outputs:

```
>> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
>> <html><body>foo<a href="http://bar">bar</a>
>> </body></html>
```

The advantage to using XPath to find the nodes is it all runs in compiled C, rather than letting Ruby do it.

Comment: VERY thorough answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that method be `start_with?`

Comment: tried that to just in case, but same error.  using rails 1.9.2.  Edited question, meant !a.starts_with?