# How to remove HTML markup from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html-safe

Let's say I have:

```
@string = "it is a <a href="#">string</a>"
```

I want to use it in different parts of my application in two ways:

- With a clickable link
- Without the clickable link (but not showing any HTML markup)

The first one can be done using `html_safe`:

```
@string.html_safe
```

It is a [string](http://www.foo.com)

How can I achieve the second one?

It is a string.

Comment: Possible Dupilcate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414267/strip-html-from-string-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can try this:

```
ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(@string)
```

See *[strip_tags(html)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags)*.

Comment: Please note that this also _adds_ HTML markup. It converts & to &amp;

Answer (score 10):

**You can try this:**

```
strip_tags(@string)
```

Answer (score 7):

For general-purpose use (e.g. web scraper):

```
puts Rails::Html::FullSanitizer.new.sanitize("<div>Hello</div><br>")
# Hello
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `nokogiri` to do the same.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922041/how-do-i-remove-http-links-with-activesupports-starts-with-using-nokogiri) tells the story.

Here in short:

This uses the XPath's `starts-with` function:

You have to first define it like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

item = Nokogiri::HTML('<a href="#">string</a>')
puts item.to_html
```

The above will give the html output. Then you can use XPath.

```
item.search('//a[not(starts-with(@href, "http://"))]').each do |a|
  a.replace(a.content)
end
puts item.to_html
```

Answer (score 1):

In Rails, see also the strip_tags method. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags

Answer (score 0):

Rails provides a method called [`strip_links`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_links), which seems to do what you want (looking at its name).

According to [its APIDock page](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/strip_links) it is a bit limited. To make it applicable to a/any string you could extend the string class:

```
class String
  def strip_links
    ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_links(self)
  end
end
```

So you can use:

```
@string.strip_links
```

Comment: strip_links gives an error if the string has no html markups. Extending the method don't give the error, but does not work for some markups, such as <em>. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh... I thought/assumed you always have a link in your string... I guess the [`sanitize` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize) removes all HTML... (It is in the same Helper module)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by upstairs, I define this function in my project

```
 def delete_html_markup(data)
    return data if data.blank?
    if data.is_a?(Array)
      data.map{ | s |  delete_html_markup(s)  }
    elsif data.is_a?(Hash)
      data.each do | k, v |
        data[k] = delete_html_markup(v)
      end
    else
      ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(data)
    end
  end
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30609974)